# Formula for how to find if Cell Contains Specific Text then delete/remove it from that Cell

Tags: excel

Been spinning my wheels for too long now so I'm looking for help. table looks like this:

[image: table 1]

I feel like it should use =if(search(replace)) but haven't found the exact combo.

Comment: You could just hold `CTRL` and push `H` to replace to "specific test" with *nothing*.

Comment: yeah - there's plenty of ways to do it, but need it in a formula.

Answer (score 1):

Use *Substitute()*.  With data in **A1**, in another cell enter:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1," - some_text","")
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

The reason *Substitute()* is good is that if " - some_text" is in there, it gets removed.  If " - some_text" is not in **A1**, then **A1** is returned un-changed *(just like in your example)*

Comment: This wasn't quite it - needed to use an if statement I believe. There's an overall formula that I wanted to throw this piece into that looks like this: ```=LOWER(IF(G2="informative",LEFT(A2,4)&" inf"&" "&RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-4),IF(G2="negative",LEFT(A2,4)&" neg"&" "&RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-4),IF(G2 = "positive",LEFT(A2,4)&" pos"&" "&RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-4)))))```

Comment: @max  See my **EDIT#1**